# CheckBoxListTile Flutter 2.0 Single Choice Selection

Tags: android, json, flutter, rest

I tried in Flutter get Data from the RESTAPI  [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leith-Marketing/public_json/2422b28c0908f0d3af51d04020ef931510c78815/football_team.json)  Using the JSON parsing method. I made the widget able to checked on the checked box but it **checked all** instead of **Single Choice**, I tried multiple ways I still couldn't get it right. This is my following code:

```
           ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              cacheExtent: 34,
              primary: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  activeColor: Const.msinAccent,
                  title:
                      Text(snapshot.data[index].name.toString().toUpperCase()),
                  value: _isChecked,
                  secondary: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].pic, scale: 13.3),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    setState(() {
                      this._isChecked = val;
                    });
                  },
                  tristate: true,
                );
              },
            );
```

Did I Did Something wrong or miss something in general?

Answer (score 0):

It is OK then, I found the solution.

```
Set selectedsubs = Set();

 ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              cacheExtent: 34,
              primary: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  activeColor: Const.msinAccent,
                  title:
                      Text(snapshot.data[index].name.toString().toUpperCase()),
                  value: selectedsubs.contains(snapshot.data[index].name),
                  secondary: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].pic, scale: 13.3),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    setState(() {
                      this._isChecked = val;
                      selectedsubs.add(snapshot.data[index].name);
                    });
                  },
                  tristate: true,
                );
              },
            );
```